# Анимация цвета в jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста ...

Подключаю плагин - jquery.color.js, но `background` не анимируется. Почему?

Вот код (пути указаны верно):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.color.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Вот код в **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/SKf7U/)** плагин здесь не подключил потому, что не знаю как подключить сторонний плагин в jsfiddle.

Пример на jsfiddle представлен с изменением свойств `css`, а не `animate`.

Необходимо, чтобы анимация происходила от `background: transparent;` до `background:#222222;`

В общем вопрос, почему не работает?

Кроме этого, `header` почему-то не перекрывает видео ... `z-index` правил, но безуспешно.
Вот код - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/SKf7U/1/

Comment: Если вам не сильно важна поддержка старыми браузерами, можете вместо всяких скриптов попробовать использовать CSS свойство transition.

Comment: Спасибо, но поддержка IE 8+ ... Поэтому без вариантов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    
        if (scrollTop < 1) {
            $('header').stop().animate({'backgroundColor':'#222222', 'opacity':'.89'}, 1400);
        } else { 
            $('header').stop().animate({'backgroundColor': 'transparent'}, 1400);
        }
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/SKf7U/3/

Библиотека jquery.color: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Библиотеку в jsfiddle подключать нужно вот так:

[image]

Для видео указывай такие параметры:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/m0Ve263Tyxo?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

И выставляй тегу `header`

```
z-index: 10 /* на свой вкус :) */
```

Comment: @lampa, спасибо, но пример не рабочий ...

А что на счет видео? (см. вопрос)...

Comment: @Astor сори, не обновил в jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SKf7U/3/

С видео тоже не сложно. Сейчас гляну

Comment: @Astor обновил ответ, см: http://jsfiddle.net/SKf7U/4/

Comment: @lampa, Роман, спасибо! А не пошлете в нужную сторону по этому вопросу? :) - http://hashcode.ru/questions/214011/html-jquery-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: @Astor я, так же как и вы, не знаю такого плагина, поэтому занялся бы  перебором имеющихся.